# Help with installation of RDkit

Tags: software-installation

I am trying to install RDkit following [this website](http://www.rdkit.org/docs/Install.html)

As it is said for installation from command line for Linux systems I typed:

`sudo apt-get install python-rdkit librdkit1 rdkit-data`

But when I import rdkit in a python script like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8
import sys
sys.path.append("/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/")
from rdkit import Chem
from rdkit.Chem import AllChem
```

terminal returns:

```
  File "script.py", line 5, in <module>
    from rdkit import Chem
ImportError: No module named rdkit
```

Any solution?

Comment: What is the output of `python -V` ?

Comment: lets see..@GAD3R

Comment: Python 2.7.13 :: Anaconda, Inc. @GAD3R